# Why if I change the name of procps's kill command (mv /usr/bin/kill /usr/bin/anotherkill) in Ubuntu 20.04, it stops working?

Tags: kill, signals

For instance, if I run *anotherkill -s 9 1234*, I get this error message:

*skill: "anotherkill" is not supported
For more details see skill(1).*

Above referenced man page doesn't help, however.
Thanks!!

PD: In Fedora 32 there's no problem if this command changes its name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because there is a single source code for the commands `kill` and `skill`, i.e. they use the very same binary:

```
$ ls -l kill skill
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 30952 Feb 27  2020 kill
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 30952 Feb 27  2020 skill
$ cmp kill skill  
$
```

At runtime, the executed command looks under what name it has been called and act accordingly.

As you rename the command with an name that is not expected by the code, the behavior is undefined.

Comment: It's still curious why `kill` and `skill` are  installed as separate but identical files, and not hardlinks to the same.

Comment: @user414777 That's a good question. There is no technical reason I'm aware of that should prevent from doing it outside being installed on a file system not supporting hardlinks.

Comment: Thanks, it's true! I've compared kill and skill commands in Fedora (where there isn't this problem) and they are different binaries, yes. Thanks a lot!

Comment: It's a question that should be asked.  There is an answer.